# Create an <iframe> element and append html content to it with jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe

Is it possible using jQuery to create an `<iframe>` element and append html content to it without having `src` attribute specified?

The problem is I need to create an `iframe` and I already have its content (I get it as AJAX response). Unfortunately, I can't specify the URL I get response from as `src` attribute. I'd like to do something like:

```
$('<iframe id="someId"/>').append(response).appendTo("#someDiv");
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('<iframe id="someId"/>').appendTo('#someDiv')
                          .contents().find('body').append(response);
```

Comment: Can you add the content to the iframe before appending it to the dom? Cuz that would be AMAZING. A million upvotes for that if I could :)

Answer (score 2):

Why use an iframe then?  Stick it all in another container.  I can't think of any advantage of the iframe except that you can load a page from a src attribute.

I suppose if you need an iframe for some other purpose, like you load in a page but you want to replace it with the ajax response, you could use jQuery to swap out the iframe for a div and back again as needed.

The other possibility is that instead of ajax, modify your ajax php script to output the full page that you want in the iframe.  Then use jQuery to change up the address of the requested page in the iframe with new parameters to display updated content.

Comment: I found a case where this is useful. My users wanted a way to print the contents of a specific section of a highly dynamic page. At first, I opened a new window and piped my contents to that, but the pop-up was tacky. So instead I used an empty iframe which I pipe the content to, and then call window.print on the iframe: window.frames['someId'].print();

Comment: Here's another case: iframes are used to overlay ActiveX controls in IE, which otherwise are above any other element. But if there's some sort of custom access control,  the only way to go is to follow the procedure in the correct answer.

Comment: If you want to report an AJAX error, and the error comes back as an HTML page, it's easiest (and probably best) to stick the whole error response in an iframe.

Comment: styling per css is easier without affecting the main document

Comment: I found using a separate <iframe> extremely useful when creating a HTML email/content editor which had its own <head><body> and <style> items.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer doesn't work for me, but following solution works:

```js
$('<iframe>', {
    id: 'someId',
    // other options like
    frameborder: 0,
    scrolling: 'no'
}).appendTo('#someDiv').on('load', function () {
    $(this).contents().find('body').append(response);
});
```