# Can I inject HTML into an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I know that I cannot style the content of an iFrame loaded from another domain. Is there a JavaScript solution that I can place in the parent window, that will allow me to write HTML into the iFrame, like `document.write <link rel="stylesheet"…`?

***OR***

Can I take content from an iFrame and place it into a DIV in the parent window?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119979/create-an-iframe-element-and-append-html-content-to-it-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a cross-domain iframe, you simply cannot.