# How to add script to an iframe and then adding an element to trigger it

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, dynamic, insert

(using jquery or just js)
Is it possible to add script to an iframe and then add an element to trigger it? This adds the script but it gives me an error in Chrome saying that the function is undefined.

```
        //create element
        var cloned = $("<input type='button'/>")

        cloned.attr('onclick', "alertUser()");
        var parent = $("#parent");
        var iframe = $('<iframe />').attr("id", "rbm_pu");
        parent.append(iframe);
        var frame = $("#rbm_pu").contents();
        frame.find("body").append(cloned);
        frame.find('body').append("<script type='text/JavaScript'>function alertUser(){alert('hello');}</script>");
```

It appears in there but says that `alertUser()` is undefined. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with the code. First DO NOT add event handlers with attr!

Comment: close if the answer is correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fiddle should lead you to the correct way:
http://jsfiddle.net/vsXYA/2/

```
<div id='parent'></div>

// first, create button and assign the callback
var button = $("<input type='button' value='click me' />");
button.click(function() {
    alert("hello");
});

// then, append the button to the freshly created iframe
$('<iframe id="someId"/>')
    .appendTo('#parent')
    .contents().find('body')
    .append(button);
```

If you insist on defining the function as a string (and I *strongly* discourage you from doing that), this works: http://jsfiddle.net/vsXYA/5/

(Took some info from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4120007/729403 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603496/729403)

Comment: Pavel, I can't thank you enough bro. Thank you for passing the knowledge and keep sharing!