# Returning a file from an HTTP POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, post

I'm trying to find a way to return a file which is generated on the fly based on user input. The user selects rows on a table where each row is a file, and presses a download link. The server (JSP) retrieves the files from the database and zips them into a file which should then be sent back to the browser to download.

I've managed to get this working via a simple `<a href="?action=testDownload"></a>` link which returns a file, but each row has about 450 characters of key to identify it. more than 4 of these is going to break the 2083 character URL limit of IE8, which my client will be using.

I know I can't do this with Ajax because javascript does not have access to the local file system, and I do not want the whole page to reload. What are the other options?

Can I create an HTTP post which doesn't reload the whole page and which also returns the file?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an iframe, insert a form and submit this form via JavaScript.

The following example is taken from [Create an <iframe> element and append html content to it with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119979/create-an-iframe-element-and-append-html-content-to-it-with-jquery)

```
$('<iframe id="someId"/>').appendTo('#someDiv')
                          .contents().find('body').append(html);
```

Where "html" would be the html of your form.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a javascript function on click of a download button which looks at all the rows selected and post it to the jsp which does the backend work.