# Access elements within dynamically created iframe (jquery 1.x)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I created an iframe with content dynamically loaded with jquery like this and I want the iframe document to access its content as soon as it has been loaded:

```
jQuery('<iframe>', {
    id: 'widgetFrm',
    width: '100%'
})
.appendTo('#widgetDiv')
.on('load', function () {
    jQuery(this).contents().find('body').append(data.html);
})
```

The frame document knows about jquery because I use

```
if (typeof(jQuery) == "undefined") {
    var iframeBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var jQuery = function (selector) { return parent.jQuery(selector, iframeBody);
}
```

there. Within the iframe, I'd like to access its div elements after everything got loaded, I'm using `jQuery(document).ready` for that (within the dynamically loaded content).

Problem: Accessing its own elements in the frame document somehow does not work with jquery 1.x in document ready block!
`document.getElementById('#someDiv')` returns null and `jQuery('#someDiv').prop('scrollHeight')` returns undefined, although the frame content has that element (accessing it when clicking a button works!). With newer jQuery versions (for instance 3.3.1) it works, but I can't change that version currently. Is there another way to do that?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you have editing access to the page within the iframe? In other words: Can you logon to the page within iframe and then edit that page?

Comment: The iframe created in the snippet would not have an src, so it's page would be about:blank

Comment: I'm now just guessing, but It might be that document.ready isn't properly triggered on the frame node.You could try to replace that with pure JS `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn, false);`

Comment: Yes I have access to the content of the data as it's my own loaded from a server. The iframe does not have a src, but data.html is valid and correctly set as the iframe's content

Comment: "but data.html is valid and correctly set as the iframe's content"  how, and where?  that's pertenent information

Comment: Also side note; `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];` <-- don't do that.  Just use `document.body`.

Comment: @Taplar data is content that I load via jsonp and jQuery.getJSON. It contains some divs in body, after that the jquery definition and then `jQuery(document).ready(
        function () { alert(document.getElementById('#someDiv')) });` and this always returns null although someDiv exists in frame content.

Comment: That doesn't explain the missing part of your question where the src of the iframe is set.

Comment: The src of the iframe is not set it all, found the way to do that in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119979/create-an-iframe-element-and-append-html-content-to-it-with-jquery